# Desktop machine tries to map network drive with the wrong credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, windows-7, mappeddrive

I'm on a Windows domain.  And I have a user that is trying to access the C$ admin share on one of our servers.  He has all the proper permissions, and usually tries to access the share via run dialogue (\server\c$...)  It does not work though.

If he goes to map a network drive, another users name is in the log on box to begin with. I'm guessing it's trying to use this users credentials to log on (username doesn't exist anymore.)

However, if he specifies his own credentials when mapping the drive, it will map successfully, then he can unmap it and the run dialogue will work fine.  but upon reboot it'll forget and go back to the old user.

Windows 7 Pro x64
Server is 08 R2
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Is there anything for the old user in the Credentials Manager?

Comment: Not really a solution, but a hack could be that you try a batch script that's run on startup to map that drive for you. I think the "dos" command is "net" - you'll have to google if you want to even entertain this very hacky idea. Granted, I think you're best off to focus on finding where the undesired settings persist from, obviously. I'm thinking they must be listed somewhere in the registry?

Comment: @Doc, in your rambling, I think you were attempting to have him use the "net use" command, but you didn't quite get there.

Comment: @DanBig - aww, now, I think I kind of did.. I gave the command name "net", cause that's it. You're now just being unreasonably kind (this is a playful sarcastic tone) to our friend Chris, giving away more of the offensively overly hackish solution (that may not really even 'solve' the problem).

Comment: Isn't there a built-in windows gui that you have to call up via "run" that'll let ya see all sorts of things that happen on startup? "msconfig" or something? Any one know what I'm thinking of? What is that thing called...? Silly brain.

Comment: Ha, I know how to do scripts, but i don't use a logon script for our organization.   I map everything through group policy.  Keep in mind that he does not actually map the drive, he just uses the run dialogue to do it.  But when he goes to map the drive and enter his own credentials then an old users creds are there.  Its possible this person used this machine at some point in time and needed to access something that the current user does not have access to.  I'm also more interested in treating the cause and not the symptoms.  Faker has the right idea i think, ill be checking that out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [cmdkey](http://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html) (which is installed by default on Windows 7 as far as I know).
With that you can list/delete/add credentials.
If the wrong one listed there you should be able to remove it.

Comment: Im gunna go ahead and give it to this guy, by the time i finally got back to him, the issue had resolved itself but this was most in the vein of what was wrong.  Thanks for all the help guys!